# equivalent SQL Queries of index match (excel) to update column in existing table

Tags: sql-server

I need to update an existing table by adding a new column. Below is the sample data for the first table which needs to be updated with the new column(Ticket_No_Calc).

[image]

And here is the sample data of the second table.

[image: Second Table]

In Excel, I use this formula in order to get the output for the new column (Ticket_No_Calc).

```
=IFERROR(IF(D2="MKT",INDEX(Second!A:A,MATCH(First!B2,Second!B:B,0),0),INDEX(Second!A:A,MATCH(First!C2,Second!B:B,0),0)),INDEX(Second!A:A,MATCH(First!A2,Second!B:B,0),0))
```

I am not sure on how to translate this formula into SQL command. Could someone please help me with this please

Thank you.

Comment: Google the `alter table` and `update` commands.

Comment: Hi, I understand the simple commands of update and alter. I can replicate the first condition (IFERROR(IF(D2="MKT",INDEX(Second!A:A,MATCH(First!B2,Second!B:B,0),0)) with the following command:

UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No
FROM First as A
LEFT JOIN Second AS B 
ON A.Doc_Header= B.Doc_No
where A.CAT = 'MKT';

But, I am not sure how to fulfill all conditions of index and match formula above in a single sql command